# Why does SO allow people to continue answering a question when one is accepted and highly voted up?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, vote-to-close, accepted-answer

Simple question, title says it all.

For example I have a few posts where the answers that are accepted are highly voted up by the community, which indicates they are, based on my questions, vastly right.

Now I am not your copy, paste programmer who lives on SO, but I do use SO for understanding issues and problems and seeing new ideas and solutions to existing issues that I cannot figure out.

Lets take an example post, call it "How to do x in x language"

The question might have an answer with a vote of 100+, while other answers that still come in years later get instantly downvoted. Why does stack allow people to continue answering after a question has accepted what they deem to be the right answer based off the info provided, the votes and maybe the example solution (keyword: example).

Why?

I could see if there was no accepted answer, or every answer was below a certain threshhold in terms of voting. But questions after 6 months, regardless of accepted answer or not, should be closed - like GitHub.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if a question is voted up. It may not be right answer. I just experience this on a post that required an answer in navigating hash tables where methods where used to manipulate the data. This was the wrong answer but it gained the check mark based on up votes. It was not the correct answer because of the methods used and not recognizing the need. The responder did not give the write answer.

Comment: Additionally, there may be *multiple* solutions to the question, and the accepted answer can be just one of them. As the tour says, "An accepted answer does not necessarily mean it's the best, though it always means that the accepted answer worked for the author of the question."

Comment: I have met several answers that are completely wrong.  They are not just inefficient, or fail to answer the,OP question, they are functional disasters but are upvoted and accepted, (multithreading).  It's best to not cut off Q&A unless there is an overriding need, (eg, an obvious ring/sock rep farm).

Answer (score 6):

Who's to say some a new technique or invention can't come along that makes the original answer obsolete. For example, an airline introduces a new route to a destination and some [travel site's](https://travel.stackexchange.com) answer that says you get from X to Y by some complicated route now gets a new answer that says you just take a direct flight with that airline. Of course you can probably still take the old route and maybe you'd need to if the new flight is full on the day you need to travel so the old answer still has occasional usefulness.

To take your example what if there's a new release of x language. Something that wasn't possible before may now be possible and something that was difficult may now be easy. That doesn't make the existing answer wrong, many people may continue to use the old release and need that old answer but anyone using the new release will be grateful of the new answer and gradually over time that answer will get upvotes.

Often answers that are instantly downvoted are simple copies of existing answers. If you're going to add an answer to a question that has upvoted answers you'd better be saying something new about that question and it better be right.